# Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I get the below error:

Error executing child request for handler,

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper

at line

```
<li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}</li>
```

Above code is in `Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")"
rel="stylesheet" 
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1><a href="/">ASP.NET MVC MUSIC
STORE</a></h1>
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li class="first">
                <a href="@Url.Content("~")" id="current">
                    Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Store/")">Store</a></li>
           <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");}</li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/StoreManager/")">
                    Admin</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("GenreMenu", "Store");}
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        built with <a href="http://asp.net/mvc">ASP.NET MVC 3</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`CartSummary` action:

```
/ GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary 
[ChildActionOnly] 
public ActionResult CartSummary() 
{ 
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext); 
    ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount(); 
    return PartialView("CartSummary"); 
}
```

More Description

```
System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
  Source=System.Web
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName)
       at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 20
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException: System.Web.HttpCompileException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=d:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml(4): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
       Source=System.Web
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       WebEventCode=0
       SourceCode=#pragma checksum "D:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "8F2BBF58AF78F990CB91A0CC0496EC7C5799E25F"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ASP {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.WebPages;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
    using System.Web.Routing;


    public class _Page_Views_ShoppingCart_CartSummary_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic> {

#line hidden


        public _Page_Views_ShoppingCart_CartSummary_cshtml() {
        }

        protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
            get {
                return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }

        public override void Execute() {


            #line 1 "D:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml"
Write(Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")",    "Index",    "ShoppingCart",
    new { id = "cart-status" }));


            #line default
            #line hidden
WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n    ");



            #line 4 "D:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml"
Write(Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart"));


            #line default
            #line hidden
WriteLiteral(";\r\n");


        }
    }
}

       StackTrace:
            at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
            at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
            at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
            at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, String virtualPath)
            at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
            at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
            at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass8.<FindPartialView>b__7(IViewEngine e)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName)
            at System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
            at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
            at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9()
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       InnerException:
```

I get another error related to this issue.I'm posing it below

I added this line, this is in `CartSummery.cshtml`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")",    "Index", 
                         "ShoppingCart", new { id = "cart-status" })

@Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");
```

but I have the following error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\App_global.asax.nsxenzgx.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Helpers\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\assembly\dl3\8a78b80f\5b89d8d7_19a3ce01\MvcMusicStore2.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\assembly\dl3\6c65bdb8\282840f1_e09fce01\EntityFramework.dll" /out:"C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\App_Web_cartsummary.cshtml.fd8dc0e0.sp2ioc_m.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\App_Web_cartsummary.cshtml.fd8dc0e0.sp2ioc_m.0.cs" "C:\Users\W8\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\c147d7a5\1dbddebf\App_Web_cartsummary.cshtml.fd8dc0e0.sp2ioc_m.1.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

d:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml(3,1): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
d:\DIL\IT\ASP.NET\MvcMusicStore2\MvcMusicStore2\Views\ShoppingCart\CartSummary.cshtml(3,7): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

Show Complete Compilation Source:
```

Here is `the CartSummary.cshtml`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { id = "cart-status" })

    @Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");
```

Comment: What does CartSummary action look like?

Comment: //  GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();
            return PartialView("CartSummary");
        }

Comment: It seems OK. I added the code to your question to make it more readable. Do you have any more detail in the exception?

Comment: Looks like there is an error in the partial view returned from CartSummary action.

Comment: Can you also post CartSummary.cshtml?

Comment: This error usually shows up when the framework has an error in rendering a view.  I would summize that there is a markup issue in your CartSummary view.  Post that or check your Intellisense when you open that file and look for errors.

Answer (score 15):

Given your CartSummary partial view, it would appear you are in some infinite loop of calling the partial view from the partial view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cart (" + ViewData["CartCount"] + ")", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { id = "cart-status" })
    
//if this is in CartSummary, then it is calling itself over and 
//over (or not at all, thus the error.)
@Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart");
```

Comment: I down voted his answer and up voted yours as yours came first and he's marked his own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Please check your partial view for errors.
I had a similar problem today and my issue was that I renamed a property of the model and in the view its not changed.

May be this is your issue too. Try it out.

Note:
Im posting it in the answer section because I dont have enough reputation to comment below your question.

Comment: Typo in partial view. D'oh

Answer (score 1):

please remove the line **@model int** from the CartSummary.cshtml.Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and it turned out I accidentally had two partial views named the same thing and the one kept recursively calling itself, changing the name of the other partial allowed the process to flow again.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like this, it means somewhere in the processing stack there is an issue. Press continue and the full error will be output onto the webpage.

In my case, I received the exception "System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper", clicked oncontinue, and then this was shown on the website:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The partial view '_Chat' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/_Chat.aspx
~/Views/Home/_Chat.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_Chat.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_Chat.ascx
~/Views/Home/_Chat.cshtml
~/Views/Home/_Chat.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_Chat.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_Chat.vbhtml
```

Easy to find once it got to this point...

Answer (score 0):

My application was returning same exception if I was logged in as certain user.

I found that I had an AuthorizeAttribute on my Controller which was changing the action result to RedirectToRoute result for that user which resulted in System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper exception because redirects from child actions doesn't make much sence.

I fixed this by adding a check to the attributes OnAuthorization method for childactions returning redirecttorouteresult and rewrite the result to EmptyResult for them.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I had just to check all links that are on the view that I'm trying to access.

> Make sure that all the controller Action have a view and run again your application, all will just fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error/exception popping up from time to time too. In my case, it was due to having `[RequireHttps]` on some of my controllers, but not all. When someone (usually a bot or spider) accessed a view on a controller that was missing that attribute, this error/exception resulted.